# Getting the latest event satisfying a condition

Tags: events, drools, drools-fusion

Is there any way that I can get the latest event which satisfies a certain predicate ?

For example, if I write this rule:

```
rule 1:
  when
    myObject: MyObject(id == "id1" && name == "name1" && type == "type1")
  then
    myObject.doSomething();
```

I want the rule to get fired only if the `MyObject` object inserted most recently with the id `"id1"` has the given name and type.
Note that at a time, there could be multiple `MyObject`'s with this id.

In essence, I want to do something like this:

```
rule 1:
  when
    myObject: (Get the latest MyObject with its id == "id1") and
    ( myObject.name == "name1" && myObject.type == "type1") )
  then
    myObject.doSomething();
```

I am using Drools 6.2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you do have events, which requires

```
declare MyObject
  @role( event )
end
```

you can write this rule:

```
rule "latest id1-name1-type1"
when
  myObj: MyObject( id == "id1", name == "name1", type == "type1" )
  not MyObject( this after myObj, id == "id1" )
then
   myObj.doSomething();
end
```

Comment: I made some changes to the answer to make it reflect what I wanted exactly.